# how to fix error of text-rendering of CSS in Netbeans

Tags: html, css, jsp, netbeans

```css
body, html{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
 color: #5a5a5a;
}
```

unknown property CSS parsing error

Comment: Maybe upgrading to last version solve it. Anyway NetBeans only warnings you but your css is ok and you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "text-rendering" property is not defined in any CSS standard. It's actually an SVG property.

Be aware that Windows, Linux and OS X each (may) have different text-rendering engines. Not to mention that different browsers each have their own text rendering defaults, so there is no guarantee that your font treatments will be displayed as intended on the user’s system.

There are four possible values:

1. auto (default)
2. optimizeSpeed
3. optimizeLegibility
4. geometricPrecision

Netbeans is just giving you warning but if you see this property will definitely work when you see you HTML in browser. So, you can ignore this else try to update netbeans once and check since SVG is a latest concept so I wonder if previous versions support some properties of SVG.
Please vote and mark this solution if it is useful.

**Thanks!**